# What is DPM doing?

Tags: dpm

Our server team has implemented System Center Data Protection Manager (DPM). It was decided that some of our non-production database servers would be backed up using DPM. After researching this, it seems that Microsoft recommends adding the account that the DPM service runs under to the SQL sysadmin role. Yikes! Does anybody know what DPM is doing in SQL Server? Can I just give the account only certain permissions to do its job?